# Dovecot with PostgreSQL users database: Password hashing

Tags: postgresql, email, passwords, postfix-mta, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a Mail Server using Postfix and Dovecot.

I have my users stored in a PostgreSQL database with bcrypt hashed passwords.

After some researching, I found ways to read users from a PostgreSQL database, but with passwords stored in plain text.

How do I set up Dovecot to read users from a PostgreSQL database with bcrypt hashed passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dovecot fully supports the [`BLF-CRYPT` password scheme](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes) since the recent 2.3 release apparently.

It shouldn't make a difference for PostgreSQL what kind of scheme is used, the password is just a text field in the database and it's stored and retrieved in its hashed textual form. The scheme used to hash is known by the first few characters of the password, for instance `$2a$` for `bcrypt`.

Hashing the password can be can be done with `doveadm -s BLF-CRYPT` and the output copied into the password field of the database in the row corresponding to the user.

For the authentication, `dovecot`, like `postfix`, expects a user-supplied SQL query with some documented placeholders in its configuration (see [`password_query`](https://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL)), so it doesn't need to assume any particular structure of a table or view of users.